# how to query multiple rows

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

i have sqlite tablewith five columns (rownum,nodeid,lat,lng,max). and some lat points are repeated in the table, for an example

```
1,21211,34.21212,8.11289,90
2,21311,34.94674,8.xx,90
3,215611,34.9934,8.xx,20
4,24311,34.121335673,8.xx,40
5,22211,34.009473,8.xx,60
6,21265,34.21212,8.9786750,70
7,21261,34.21212,8.9786754,80
```

as you see the latitude value is repeated in the 1st,6th and the 7th rows, and what i want to do is, to make the query return the 
longitude value of the latitude i am searching for. for an example, given the code posted below, 
when i call getLngs(34.21212) the query should return a list containing 
8.11289,8.9786750 and 8.9786754

the code posted below returns only one value

**code**:

```
public ArrayList getLngs(String lat) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT lng FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE lat = " + lat + " And lng IS NOT NULL", null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("lng")));
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: which of the three values is returned? might help in debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this maybe it will work-

```
public ArrayList getLngs(String lat) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT lng FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE lat = " + lat + " And lng IS NOT NULL", null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("lng")));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: i dont think it is much different :P so it didnt work then? hmmm let me think some more :)

Comment: the secret was in do-while, as it allows to add the value to the list then moves the cursor

Answer (score 0):

just remove `c.moveToFirst();`  from your code that move your cursor to First Position so you have only last value.